# Facebook API finding status created time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

When I call the `/statuses` endpoint I only get a `updated_time` field and not a `created_time` field (like I do when calling `/photos` or `/links`). It seems that `updated_time` is the time this post was last liked or commented, and it appears even setting the `since` parameter in the query returns statuses that were created before `since` but were updated after.

Is there any reason for this difference between `/statuses` vs. `/photos` and `/links`?
Can I get a `created_time` for a `status` and query `since` accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Better use FQL for this time. It has always been more complete than Graph.

```
SELECT time, message FROM status WHERE uid = me()
```

> **time** *uid*
>   UNIX timestamp of the date and time the status message was posted

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/status/

Comment: FQL works fine - but I think in most cases you don't need it. Especially for such easy requests like easy access data via og.